# ReactJS code not working when refactoring - What is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Firstly, let me apologise for not posting any 'actual code', but I am unsure of which section is kicking up an error.

I have attempted to refactor code found for a simple CRUD app in React, moving it from CodePen to CodeSandbox. However, I cannot seem to get it to work... Can somebody please give me a pointer as to what is going wrong?

[image]

I have seen this sort of error before. The usual cause is unclosed HTML tags, but I cannot seem to find any that are incomplete.

I have refactored numerous functions which may be a possible cause, from the format:

```
var RecipeAdd = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { showModal: false };
  },
  close: function() {
    globalTitle = "";
    globalIngredients = [];
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }, 
  // more functions like this
```

to a format more like:

```
class RecipeAdd extends React.Component {
  getInitialState = () => {
    return { showModal: false };
  }
    close = () => {
    globalTitle = "";
    globalIngredients = [];
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }
  // more functions like this
```

Original code: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SedatUygur/pen/jWgJdv)

Refactored: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1v53jl98v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by @jb cazaux, you are missing quite a lot of matching curly braces. But on top of this you have defined `render()` more than once in this [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1v53jl98v) and that is not allowed in react. You also call `render` to a DOM element more than once and that is not allowed as well. Another thing, well, at least from the sandbox provided, you are calling `ReactDOM.render` but this is not defined. Rather call `render` since that is the function you have destructured from the react-dom package. Also, you have no `state` defined but somewhere in the code, you try accessing this.

I have forked your sandbox and fixed the issues. For clarity and ease of spotting the problem, I have removed the parts that have nothing to do with the problem you are facing. Have a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z347p3wymm)

PS: In that sandbox there is no DOM element with id of "button" but "root", so I have altered that as well.

Comment: Thanks for everything @brandNew - Must still be suffering from a case of the Mondays! Spotting missing curly braces is a nightmare when your IDE isn't picking it up >:(

Comment: Hahaha, be careful from the get go is my advice. Glad this helped. All the best. Cheers

Comment: I just did. But people are finding it useless, so yeah.

Answer (score 3):

missing

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

or if you want to use your

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

just write

```
// Render the add button (and modal)
render(<RecipeAdd />, document.getElementById("button"));
```

There is a missing } at the end of var IngredientList = () => { and an extra coma ','
Missing } at the end of the class declaration
Missing var before update = () => {

root, not button:
    ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById("root"));

Comment: That doesnot seems to solve the problem. There are also other issues that is creating the problem. Did you run the sandboxed code

Comment: The is no need for the extra coma by the way, since the following statement is another declaration.